# Visual studio 2019 Non-legit optimization in map::operator[]?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

While migrating to MSVC 2019, I found out a strange behavior of `std::map::operator[]`.

In short, the compiler optimizations increase the size of the map *before* evaluating the right-handside of the operator.

Small example (tested with MSVC 16.9.6)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>

using Key = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1>>;
using Map = std::map<Key, size_t>;

void dummy(Map& map, Key key)
{
    map[key] = map.size();
}

int main() {
    Map map;
    dummy(map, std::chrono::seconds{ 1 });

    for (const auto& item : map) {
        std::cout << "key:" << item.first.count() << " value:" << item.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output in `debug` mode is as expected:

```
key:1 value:0
```

However, in `release` things are different:

```
key:1 value:1
```

Did I miss something? Or is that unwanted?

At least, clang does not behave the same: https://godbolt.org/z/fE91M3xxe

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you expect left or right side of that expression evaluated in particular order?

Comment: Well we're talking about `T& operator[]( const Key& key );` so I expect the argument `key` to be evaluated before the operator itself.

Comment: In release mode, all kinds of optimizations are allowed. It is entirely possible that there is no `operator[]` and the entire thing is just inlined.

Comment: "Well we're talking about T& operator[]( const Key& key );" no we are talking about assignment operator. Why do you expect left or right side of assignment evaluated in particular order?

Comment: Which standard do you use? C++17 imposes `map.size()` to be computed before `map[key]` ([evaluation order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order))

Comment: @Slava you're right, sorry I mixed things up. So I have no real reason to expect rhs to be evaluated before lhs, only the fact that previous MSVC did rhs first.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks a lot for the link, indeed switching to C++17 solves the problem. Default was c++14 in this case.

Comment: *"In short, the compiler optimizations increase the size of the map before evaluating the right-handside of the operator."* -- interestingly, this statement is true, except for the intended meaning of "the operator". The intended meaning is the subscript operator, but reading "the operator" as "the assignment operator" makes it true. Assumptions can be hazardous to debugging. :)

Comment: @JaMiT Yes let's say I was lucky on that one ^^